# How could I launch multiple container at a time shared one Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to launch hundreds of container with one command.

### Container A will change directory to `a` then run `a.rb` when it is launched

### Container B will change directory to `b` then run `b.rb` when it is launched

> Container ... will change directory to `...` then run `....rb` when it is launched

All of those containers should share the same Dockerfile.

[image]

I need to switch to correspoding folder then execute script

But I got error

> failed to exec: exec: "cd": executable file not found in $PATH

```
  a:
    build: .
    command: cd a ; ruby a.rb
    volumes:
        - .:/crawler
    ports:
      - 5901:5901
  b:
    build: .
    command: cd b ; ruby b.rb
    volumes:
        - .:/crawler
    ports:
      - 5902:5902
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 2):

First, the image built from the Dockerfile must include `a/r.rb` and `b/b.rb`.
That means the Dockerfile has 2 `COPY` directives, to include those scripts.

Since you want only *one* Dockerfile, producing *one* image, you should include in it a `COPY start.sh`  script and `CMD start.sh` directive. That script (now included in the image) which would run `a/r.rb` or `b/r.rb` depending on an environment variable (for example `MUSTRUN`).

```
docker run -e MUSTRUN=a myimage
or 
docker run -e MUSTRUN=b myimage
```

Keep it mind your container will stop once the `r.rb` script exits.
To keep it running, you would need to change the `start.sh` in order to loop indefinitely, a bit like "[A Daemonized Hello world](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerizing/#a-daemonized-hello-world)".